# Relate a record to calendar in SugarPro

Tags: php, sugarcrm

Normally in Sugar if we create calls, meetings and tasks it ll be related to calendar(display in calendar with the subject).
Right now I have created one custom module where I need to relate it to calendar whenever I create a new record.(Same like calls, meetings and tasks)
I struck with this thing, What can I do for this to relate the record with calendar at the specified date time in that record when I create it.

Comment: What have you tried? There is relationship in Studio where you can specify  it...

Comment: for calendar there is no relationship, through files I'm trying to add automatically whenever the record is newly created.